# Displaying drupal view twice

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I have a view in drupal that I would like to display twice, in different ways.

I'm creating two content sliders. It looks like a gallery using SlideDeck. I have one slider that displays a detailed display of the content and the other slider is a thumbnail view that when clicked, changes the first slider. This functions similar to the slider on the homepage of ESPN or WWE.com.

The view I have is connected to a nodequeue.

it would look something like:

```
<div id="slide-contain">
    <div id="slide1">
        <dl>
            <dd>
                cycle through the view
                <?php print $rows; ?>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2">
        <dl>
            <dd>
                cycle through the view again
                <?php print $rows; ?>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my answer is going to be a bit vague because I've never used the slider you are using.

In your situation where you want the same view 2 different ways, you might want to look at Views Attachment Displays. This will allow you to create a separate display for your thumbnails and then attach it to your regular one. You can then set it to render before the main view which would basically iterate the view twice.

I tried finding a good explainer on them, but couldn't find much. If you install the FAQ module, the views it installs use attachments to present the classic "questions on top" display.

FWIW I did a similar slider using [Awkward Showcase](http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/) and views. I liked it because it wasn't necessary to first iterate through the thumbnails, and then iterate through main content. Instead each piece of content was contained within a single div, allowing me to theme a single row.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually came up with a way that works perfectly for me... I have a block with two views_embed_view and applied the theme templates to each of the views. Works perfectly!